# Bash script variable placement

Tags: bash

I started to learn Bash scripting and I'm using [Bash scripting tutorial](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php)

There it says

> Before Bash interprets (or runs) every line of our script it **first checks to see if any variable names are present**. For every variable it has identified, it replaces the variable name with its value. Then it runs that line of code and begins the process again on the next line.

So does Bash first run through the whole script to find variables? I'm not sure whether this is what the author tried to say but if yes I guess it is not correct?

when I execute:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "hello $USERR"



USERR=John
```

I get `hello`as result.

If I run:

```
#!/bin/bash


USERR=John

echo "hello $USERR"
```

then i get `hello John` as result.

Comment: I would disregard a tutorial whose first code sample does the most elementary mistake of not quoting parameter expansions (and forgetting the `--`, and not checking for failure of commands...). [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So does Bash first run through the whole script to find variables?

Nope. As you yourself discovered in your example, Bash scripts are executed from top to bottom.

A good practice is to define all variables that you need at the top of your script.

Comment: However, Bash does first run through *lines* to find variables. `x=1; x=2 echo "$x"` prints `1` because `$x` is substituted before `x=2 echo "$x"` is run.

Answer (score 9):

That's a very sloppy way of saying that the shell scans each command for expansions, such as *for example* variables (but also command substitutions etc.)

The text *could* be interpreted to imply that the shell reads the whole script and looks for variables on every line before execution.  That is not so.  It processes the script command by command, not line by line. A command could span several lines.  A command is not processed until the shell interpreter gets to it in its execution of the script.

The `bash` shell does the following with each command before executing it:

1. brace expansion
2. tilde expansion
3. parameter and variable expansion
4. arithmetic expansion
5. command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion)
6. word splitting
7. pathname expansion
8. quote removal

Comment: yes, this is how I interpreted the line. I'll go through the material anyway but are there any books, web sites  worth looking at ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @blablatrace I'd recommend https://unix.stackexchange.com as a good resource for learning how to use and program in the shell, even though the quality is somewhat variable at times. The community is generally friendly too. Check out [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) too (a bit empty in there sometimes though).

Comment: Maybe you should be more clear in what you mean by 'processes redirections' -- I understand what's about (that eg.  'a=">"; echo yes $a foo' won't write 'yes' to 'foo'); but redirections are certainly processed AFTER expansions, eg. 'a="a b c"; echo >$a' is an error, which shows the shell tries to make sense of the redirection after it does variable expansion. And variable assignments are also special in the same manner as redirections -- 'q=a; $q=12 cmd' will try to run a command named 'a=12', not 'cmd' with a var a = 12 in its environment.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple simple commands on the same line (separated by `;`, `||` or `&&`), they're expanded and executed one at a time. Thus, `foo="some value"; echo "$foo"` prints `some value` because the reference to `$foo` doesn't get expanded until *after* the assignment command has run. BTW, commands can also be separated by `&`, but that's a bit of a special case; with that, the first command gets run in the background so the second command doesn't wait for it to finish.

Comment: Other good bash scripting resources: [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org) and [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), the [Bash Hacker's Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org), and [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to check your scripts for common problems.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, that bit about expansions was wrong (now removed). I was careful not to say that commands are processed "line by line" (relating to your second comment). Newlines, `;` and `&` as well as `|`, `||` and `&&` are command terminators (and `;;` in `case` statements).